# Samesite=none cookies not saved on ios

Tags: rest, authentication, cookies, samesite

I have written a REST API with jwt authentication. I store my token in http-only, secure, samesite=none cookie and everything works on desktop and on android, but it doesn't work on IOS except i turn off Prevent Cross-tracking and the it works only for Safari and not for Chrome

Answer (score 0):

To be allowed to set a cookie with **samesite=none**, then it must be set over **HTTPS** and the cookies must be marked with the **secure** attribute as well.

Otherwise the browser will reject it.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: The cookie is secure and over https and again, the same thing